# Why this recursion gives a segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, recursion

The following program tries to calculate the sum from `1` to `n`. I want to see the intermediate output, so I add the following `std::cout` line, however when run the program it report the segmentation fault, **How to understand this? What to do to output the intermediate results?**

```
#include <iostream>

int sum_to(int value)
{   
    std::cout << "sum to " << value << " is " << sum_to(value)  << '\n';
    if(value <=1)   {
        return 1;
    }
    else    {
        return sum_to(value-1) + value;
    }

}

int main()
{
    sum_to(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger?

Comment: sum_to s calling itelf in the std::cout

Comment: You build an endless recursion, as you are calling `sum_to(value)` in `sum_to`.

Comment: You didn't get a stack overflow error?

Comment: @George No, just `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Comment: huh, i'm not sure why, but anyway all the memory required for sum_to is being allocated every time it's called(in theory), and it's being called in an infinite recursive loop, and so you when you run out of stack space, you should get a stack overflow error but I guess `Segmentation fault `( attempting to access memory that doesn't belong to that you shouldn't, in this case to allocate more memory for each new stack frame ) is valid too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stack overflow exception with recursion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33766776/stack-overflow-exception-with-recursion)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the code you should use:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int sum_to(int value)
{   
    if(value <= 1)
        return 1;
    return sum_to(value-1) + value;
}

int main()
{
    int value = 5;
    std::cout << "sum to " << value << " is " <<  sum_to(value) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to print intermediate status you'll need one more variable `temp` to store the intermediate result and print it:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int sum_to(int value)
{   
    if(value <= 1)
        return 1;
    int temp = sum_to(value-1) + value;
    std::cout << "sum to " << value << " is " <<  temp << '\n';
    return temp;
}

int main()
{
    int value = 5;
    std::cout << "sum to " << value << " is " <<  sum_to(value) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

---

The issue was that you were calling `sum_to` in a place you shouldn't because `value` was always the same:

```
int sum_to(int value)
{   
    std::cout << "sum to " << value << " is " << sum_to(value)  << '\n';
    if(value <=1)   {                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this call
        return 1;
    }
    else    {
        return sum_to(value-1) + value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but no need to define `temp` as a global variable.

Comment: Or maybe you have a reason for doing this?

Comment: @buzhidao you were right, the scope wasn't correct?

Answer (score 3):

You have an infinite recursion *before* you check for the termination condition. Change that `std::cout` to not call `sum_to` recuirsively.

Comment: `sum_to(value)  << '\n';` cause the endless call of the function. The following if statement never run even once?

Comment: @buzhidao No, not even once.

Answer (score 0):

There are few improvements you can make:

1. Remove endless recursion by removing first cout.
2. Add log/cout after recursive call.

   ```
   int sum_to(int value)  
   {  
       if(value <=1) {  
           return 1;  
       }  
       else {  
           int result = sum_to(value-1);  
           cout << "Sum to " << (value-1) << " is " << result << '\n';  
           return result + value;  
       }  
   }
   ```

Comment: Don't know why but code formatting is not working - Used {}.

Comment: You'll have a lot of useless calls here... (formatting didn't worked because the code sample was in the list element, needed 8 spaces instead of 4)

Comment: @ThomasAyoub : First of all, thank you for the edit, and didnt think the list was still in affect. And yes, had removed the multiple call in return statement, but forgot in cout.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your `else` body with:

```
    int intermediate = sum_to(value-1) + value;
    cout << "Intermidiate: " << intermediate << endl;
    return intermediate;
```